# How to use optimal parameters identified GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

I am using `GridSearchCV` to identify optimal parameters but I am not sure how to actually use the optimal parameters, that is, in the code below, in the third line, my results do not change after altering the first line (e.g. if I change the parameter space, or replace recall with precision etc.)

```
cv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, cv=len(range(2014,2019)), scoring='recall', refit=True)
cv.fit(X,y)
y_pred = cross_val_predict(cv, X, y, cv=len(range(2014,2019)))
```

Is there a way to ensure, that whatever optimal parameters are identified in `GridSearchCV` are actually also used going forward whenever I call `cv.predict`?

Comment: Not sure why you use `cross_val_predict` in your 3rd line, instead of the expected `cv.predict`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GridSearchCV` already does what you want by default, unless you set `refit=False`. As stated by the `GridSearchCV` [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html):

> **refit : boolean, or string, default=True**
>   Refit an estimator using the best found parameters on the whole dataset.
>
> For multiple metric evaluation, this needs to be a string denoting the scorer is used to find the best parameters for refitting the estimator at the end.
>
> The refitted estimator is made available at the `best_estimator_` attribute and **permits using `predict` directly on this `GridSearchCV` instance**.
>
> Also for multiple metric evaluation, the attributes `best_index_`, `best_score_` and `best_params_` will only be available if refit is set and all of them will be determined w.r.t this specific scorer.
>
> See scoring parameter to know more about multiple metric evaluation.

So, whenever you call `cv.predict` the best estimator, which has been refit, makes the prediction.

In your case, the results are the same probably because the best estimator scores the highest on **all metrics**.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. That could be, I will test of a few additional metrics. thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.predict), it says:

> `predict(x)` Call predict on the estimator with the best found parameters.

Essentially after fitting, calling predict uses the optimal estimator. If you want to double check your params you can after fitting see that the best parameters are stored in the class attribute `best_params_`.

As for why your results don't change after altering the first line I would guess that it's coincidentally coming to the same best parameters: or that there are multiple best parameters.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you, I will double check that with a bunch of different parameters.